# Angular 4 - Converting events to observable streams

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm fairly new to Rxjs and Angular 4 and can't get my head around how to do this.

Template:

```
<div class="btn-group cp">
   <input [colorPicker]="bgColor" 
   (colorPickerChange)="colorChanged()" 
   [style.background]="bgColor">
</div>
```

colorChanged() gets called by the colorPickerChnage on mousemove. I want to have something like this in my component:

```
colorChanged$.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

(It will have some debounce and more subscribers, that's why I'd like to have it as an observable.)

Comment: You can subscribe to an `EventEmitter` and emit from either the functions itself or use something like `HostListener` for the `mousemove` event of your component.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it.

Template:

```
<div class="btn-group cp">
   <input [colorPicker]="bgColor" 
   (colorPickerChange)="colorChanged(bgColor)" 
   [style.background]="bgColor">
</div>
```

And then in the component:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

  colorChanged$ = new Subject<string>();

  colorChanged(bgColor) {
     this.colorChanged$.next(bgColor)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.colorChanged$.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
  }
```

Comment: Although this works, turns out this is not the "Rx" way of doing it. Read the article from Ben Lesh: [On The Subject Of Subjects (in RxJS)](https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93)

Comment: Probably you can use Observable.fromEvent(event.target, 'event type')
Take a look at this - [link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html)

Comment: What would event.target be in this case, how would you connect fromEvent to colorPickerChange? The fromEvent examples only show the most basic use case, a click event on document, and relying on DOM events is not the "Angular" way.

Comment: You can even do `<div (colorPickerChange)="colorChanged$.next(bgColor)" ...></div>` directly without needing the intemediate function.